# Найти прямое совпадение в .txt и удалить строку node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет. Есть следующая функция:

```
//наблюдаем за файлом users.txt
fs.watchFile('users.txt', function(curr, prev) {
    //получаем данные о пользователе
    var file_handle = fs.openSync("users.txt", "r", 0644);
    var data = fs.readSync(file_handle, 10000, null, 'utf-8');
    var users = data[0].split('\r\n').map(function (val) {
        var obj = val.split(':');
        return {email: obj[0], password: obj[1]};
    });
    fs.closeSync(file_handle);

    var wallet = 'hereiswallet';    

    //цикл для каждого пользователя
    for (var i=0; i < users.length; i++) {  
        //подготавливаем данные 
         childArgs = [
          path.join(__dirname, 'prod.js'),
          users[i].email, users[i].password, wallet
        ];  

        //делаем запрос к файлу
        childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, function(err, stdout, stderr) {       

            var arr = stdout.split(':');
            var str = arr[1]+':'+arr[2];

            if (arr[0] == 1) {              
                fs.appendFile('success.txt', str, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('success');
                    }
                })
            }   
            else if (arr[0] == 0) {             
                fs.appendFile('wrong_password.txt', str, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('success');
                    }
                })
            }   

        });
    }   
});
```

Проблема в участках

```
fs.appendFile('success.txt', str, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('success');
                }
})
```

Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы при внесении данных в success.txt, они удалялись из users.txt. Как это можно сделать?
Сделать это нужно в этом месте:

```
else {
     console.log('success');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
Каждый раз открывать заново файл, парсить его, искать нужную строку, вырезать 
и записывать - во-первых слишком накладно и муторно, 
а во-вторых каждая запись будет триггерить watch.
У нас уже есть массив users, так что логично было бы работать с ним. 
После того как все users будут перебраны - 
просто записать всех оставшихся оптом обратно в файл.
*/

let self_triggering_protect = false;
fs.watchFile('users.txt', function(curr, prev) {
    if(self_triggering_protect) {
        self_triggering_protect = false;
        return;
    }
    var file_handle = fs.openSync("users.txt", "r", 0644);
    var data = fs.readSync(file_handle, 10000, null, 'utf-8');
    // Не надо здесь \r\n. 
    // CR+LF - только под windows, а по LF (т.е. просто \n) можно разбить на строки и в UNIX и в Windows. А trim уберёт \r, заодно с пробелами и \t
    var users = data[0].split('\n').map(function (val) {
        var obj = val.split(':');
        return {email: obj[0].trim(), password: obj[1].trim()};
    }); 
    fs.closeSync(file_handle);

    var wallet = 'hereiswallet';
    // Превратим массив users в массив обещаний 
    var promises = users.map(user => new Promise(resolve => 
         childProcess.execFile(binPath, [path.join(__dirname, 'prod.js'), user.email, user.password, wallet], (err,stdout) => {
                var arr = stdout.split(':');
                var str = arr[1]+':'+arr[2];
                if (+arr[0] === 1) { 
                    fs.appendFile('success.txt', str, err => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log('success');
                            // Удаляем юзера из массива users
                            users.splice(users.indexOf(user), 1);
                        }
                    })
                    resolve();
                }else if (+arr[0] === 0) {             
                    fs.appendFile('wrong_password.txt', str, err => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log('wrong_password');
                        }
                        resolve();
                    })
                };  
        })
    ));
    // Дождемся всех, и запишем оставшихся users обратно в файл
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        self_triggering_protect = true;
        fs.writeFile("users.txt", users.map(user => `${user.email}:${user.password}`).join('\n'), err => err ? console.error(err) : console.log('Finished'));
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));    
});
```

Comment: Привет! Да, все супер, но есть две проблемы: 1. как сделать, чтобы даже при ошибке действие скрипта не останавливалось? Ибо если файл будет сохранен пустым случайно, действие скрипта прекратится. 2. не убираются строки из файла users.txt после действия скрипта. Есть еще проблема, не знаю, как пофиксить - данные в файл могут записываться во время выполнения скрипта. можно ли стирать те аккаунты, которые уже прошли через скрипт?

Comment: т.е. "оставшихся" пользователей не может быть, они должны быть раскиданы либо по wrong_password, либо success